# Algorithm to match roots between two string lists

Tags: algorithm

**The problem:**

I am using a watch service to monitor a directory for input so I can fire an event once I have two (semi)matching input files. The problem I have is: **If I have two lists, each containing strings that may differ how can I find matching roots between lists as they occur.**

The filename structure looks like this:

```
<companyname>-<ordernum><postfix>.csv
```

so for example:

```
list1 could contain: 
    mycomp-1234.csv
    mycomp-4567.csv
    newcomp-7891.csv
    oldcomp-3376.csv

list2 could contain:
    mycomp-2232_items.csv
    newcomp-13123_items.csv
    oldcomp-87078777_items.csv
    mycomp-1234_items.csv
```

I want to find, and fire the event as soon as a match occurs between lists. A match being any filename, less the suffix. i.e. mycomp-1234 would return a match for both lists.

**What I'm looking for**

I'm looking to find the most efficient manner to do this. I know I can iterate over each list comparing values, but I am sure there is a more efficient way to do this.

I do not need code, I'd rather learn this by myself, so a push in the right direction is perfect. If your fingers make you write code, please write pseudo code so it can benefit as many languages as possible.

And no, this is not homework. For those of you intensely curious folk this is to perform EDI transformations from csv to X12 EDI files.

Comment: Take a look at [LCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)

Comment: A good first step is to sort the lists.

Comment: What is the expected input size? What is the needed performance? How do you define a `suffix` in `A match being any filename, less the suffix.`?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev The suffix would be -items. For performance, as much as possible. Input size can vary, sometimes significantly as far as filenames go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort the lists alphabetically then compare the values and step forward in the list that has the smaller value.  If the lists have any elements in common the values will match.

Comment: Thank you for not providing the code. Although Joop's answer is correct and works as expected, I was looking for a push in the right direction, rather than having the work done for me.

Answer (score 2):

A side by side comparison of two sorted lists.

```
Collections.sort(list1);
Collections.sort(list2);
int i1 = 0;
int i2 = 0;
while (i1 < list1.size() && i2 < list.size()) {
    String name1 = list1.get(i1);
    String name2 = list2.get(i2);
    String[] parts1 = name1.split("[-_.]");
    String[] parts2 = name2.split("[-_.]");
    if (parts1.length < 3) {
        ++i1;
        continue;
    }
    if (parts2.length < 3) {
        ++i2;
        continue;
    }
    int cmp = parts1[0].compareTo(parts1[0]);
    if (cmp == 0) {
        cmp = parts1[1].compareTo(parts1[1]);
    }
    if (cmp < 0) {
        ++i1;
        continue
    }
    if (cmp > 0) {
        ++i2;
        continue
    }
    // Found match:
    ...
    ++i1;
    ++i2;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

An online method: Maintain a binary search tree containing all the current filenames.  Use as keys the relevant bits of filenames.  For example, the key for either `newcomp-7891.csv` or `newcomp-7891_items` is `newcomp-7891`.  Each time the watch service reports a directory event, you can delete disused names and can attempt to add new names to the tree.  If a key already is in the tree, fire your desired event.

A hash table can be used similarly, if the hash implementation supports deletion of keys when filenames are removed.

The question asks for “the most efficient manner to do this”.  Note that this method is far more efficient than sorting the lists from scratch each time a directory event occurs.  At an event with k additions and deletions, it uses O(k·lg n) time if the dataset has n entries, so over a period of time where the average tree size is n and m additions/deletions occur, in u directory events, it will do O(m·lg n) work.  By contrast, the sort-each-time methods suggested in other answers will do O(u·n·lg n) work, which is much more.